# Merge several TIN in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, merge, tin

I have plenty of very tiny adjacent TIN chunks in a [PostgreSQL 15](https://www.postgresql.org/) / [PostGIS 3.4](https://postgis.net/) database.

I would like to merge them all into a *single* one.

I've tried both [`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) and [`ST_3DUnion`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DUnion.html) but they both gives a `GeometryCollection` whereas I want to have a single TIN.

Here's a dummy snippet of code:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_3DUnion(
    ST_GeomFromText('TIN (
        ((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
        ((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)))'
    ),
    ST_GeomFromText('TIN (
        ((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
        ((2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2)))'
    )        
))
--------
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (
    TIN Z (((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
           ((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6))),
    TIN Z (((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
           ((2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2)))
)
(1 row)
```

What I would like as an output is:

```sql
TIN (
((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.6,2.5 1.2 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
((2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6)),
((2.4 1.1 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.6,2.45 1.02 4.2,2.4 1.1 4.2))
)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

TIN support is unfortunately pretty limited in PostGIS.  You probably have to merge the TIN values together in the textual domain, by stripping the leading `TIN(` and trailing `)`, concatenating with a comma separator, and adding the leading `TIN(` and trailing `)` again.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm currently doing as a workaround, but I don't like such "tinkering" because it's kind of an antipattern for me.

Comment: In the absence of this functionality in PostGIS, that's probably the best that can be done.  It should be a fairly robust solution (i.e. unlikely to break with new releases of PostGIS).